# How to change the text color on the footer with colormag theme wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

i tried to add some code in the `style.css` that i found on stack but with no result.
Need some help
Theme: colormag

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this class to your style.css

```
.footer-socket-left-sectoin {
color: #999}
```

The copyright will appear in light grey then! Thats it.